# 404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server

Tags: laravel, http, https, http-status-code-404, hosting

my laravel website is on a hosting which i use normally, but yesterday, i try to download the code into my computer, to put a command in terminal of vscode

```bash
composer require railsware/mailtrap-php symfony/http-client nyholm/psr7
```

it worked perfectly on localhost, then i deployed it into my hosting (i deleted the previous code) and i can't access my website on https (i installed ssl, and used to acccess https without any error). Whenever i try to access https://mywebsite it said

> 404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server!

mywebsite is askmeprivate.io.vn
its a laravel website

i try to re-install ssl, or setting .htaccess file in public, but it didn't work, i can't access https://mywebsite

Comment: Anything in the server logs?